# Trigonometry Two Variables in Complex Number

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

If $x,y\in \left (0,\pi/2\right )$ satisfy
\begin{align*}
\left (\cos(x)+ i \sin(y)\right )^{2023} &= \cos(2023x) + i\sin(2023y)\\
\left (\cos(x) + i\sin(y)\right )^{2024} &= \cos(2024x) + i\sin (2024y),
\end{align*}
prove that
$\left (\cos(x) + i\sin (y)\right )^{2025} = \cos(2025x)+i\sin(2025y).$

---

So far all I have done is manipulate with $\sin(2025x)=\sin(2024x+x)$ and
$$(\cos(x)  +i\sin(y))^{2025} = (\cos(x)+i\sin (y))^2(\cos(x) + i\sin(y))^{2023}. $$
But, the results were very messy.

Comment: Try expanding $\sin(2024x+x)$ and $\cos(2024x+x)$ using the angle addition formulas. You should be able to get $(\cos(x) +i \sin(x))$ times something…

Comment: Another approach is to use the given information to show that $y = x$, from which it would follow that $(\cos x + i\sin y)^n=\cos nx + i\sin ny$ for all $n$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $(\cos{x}+i\sin{y})^n = \cos{nx}+i\sin{ny}$ holds for positive integers $n$ and $n+1$, then it holds for all positive integers $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3509930/if-cosxi-sinyn-cosnxi-sinny-holds-for-positive-integers-n-a) - found in the "Related" section on the RHS.